# Behaviour should change due to authorization at service or controller level?

Tags: java, service, controller

I want to fetch some resources and I expect 2 different behaviours depending on the connected user.
If the user is an admin, he retrieves all the resources, otherwise he only retrieves the resources he can access.

Are there some recommendations about such a case? What is the best way to do this and why?

Here are the different options I found :

1. At the controller level :

```
@GetMapping(value = "/myresources")
public void exportKdSchema(HttpServletResponse response) {
    User user = getConnectedUser();
    if(user.isAdmin()) {
        resourceService.getAllResources();
    }
    else {
        resourceService.getAllResourcesByUser(user);
    }
}
```

2. At the service level :

```
@GetMapping(value = "/myresources")
public void exportKdSchema(HttpServletResponse response) {
    User user = getConnectedUser();
    resourceService.getResourcesByUser(user)
}

@Service 
public class ResourceService{
    public List<Resource> getResourcesByUser(User user) {
        if(user.isAdmin()) {
            resourceRepository.findAll()
        }
        else {
            resourceRepository.findAllByUserId(user.getId())
        }
    }
}
```

3. Should I create 2 controllers :

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('RESOURCES_ALL')")
@GetMapping(value = "/myresources")
public void exportKdSchema(HttpServletResponse response) {
    resourceService.getAllResources();        
}

@GetMapping(value = "/myresources/{userId}")
public void exportKdSchema(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId) {
    resourceService.getAllResourcesByUser(user);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will probably get a lot of different opinions on how it should be done. I would personally create two different endpoints for user and admin functionality:

`/resources/my` and `/admin/resources/{userId}`

Think about the case where some admin (your client) might also use the system as a simple user. System admining and normal usage are two different usecases, so I wouldn't mix them together.

Plus you also have more predictable responses from your endpoints that are independent of user roles.

Prefixing `/admin` endpoints may also allow for easier configuration, depending on the Access Control granularity you might need.